# Implementing Jena Dataset provider over MongoDB

Tags: jena

I have started to implement a set of classes that provide a direct interface to MongoDB for persistence, similar in spirit to the now-unmaintained SDB persistor implementation for RDBMS.
I am using the time-honored technique of creating the necessary concrete classes from the interfaces and doing a `println` in each method, therein allowing me to trace the execution.   I have gotten all the way to where the engine is calling out to my cursor set up:

```
public ExtendedIterator<Triple> find(Node s, Node p, Node o) {

    System.out.println("+++ MongoGraph:extenditer:find(" + s + p + o + ")");

    // TBD Need to turn s,p,o into a match expression!  Easy!                  
    MongoCursor cur = this.coll.find().iterator();

    ExtendedIterator<Triple> curs = new JenaMongoCursorIterator(cur);

    return curs;
}
```

Sadly, when I later call this:

```
        while(rs.hasNext()) {
            QuerySolution soln = rs.nextSolution() ;
            System.out.println(soln);
        }
```

It turns out `rs.hasNext()` is always false even though material is present in the `MongoCursor` (I can debug-print it in the find() method).  Also, the trace print in the `next()` function in my concrete iterator `JenaMongoCursorIterator`  (which extends NiceIterator which I believe is OK) is never hit.  In short, the basic setup seems good but then the engine never cranks the iterator on `find()`

Trying to use SDB as a guide is completely overwhelming for someone not intimately familiar with the software architecture.  It's fully factored and filled with interfaces and factories and although that is excellent, it is difficult to nav.

Has anyone tried to create their own persistor implementation and if so, what are the basic steps to getting a "hello world" running?  Hello World in this case is ANY implementation, non-optimized, that can call `next()` on something to produce a `Triple`.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR:  It is now working.
I was coding too eagerly and `JenaMongoCursorIterator` contained a method `hasNexl` which of course did not override `hasNext` (with a `t` ) in the default implementation of `NiceIterator` which returns false.
This is the sort of problem that eclipse and visual debugging and tracing makes a lot easier to resolve than regular jdb.  jdb is fine if you know the software architecture pretty well but if you don't, the multiple open source files and being able to mouse over vars and such provides a tremendous boost in the amount of context that can be created to home in on the problem.